# SWRevealViewController and pauseInteractiveTransition not implemented

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I use SWRevealViewController in a lot of my projects.  Since updating to Swift 3  with an iOS deployment target of 10.0 or higher, I am now getting a warning Method 'pauseInteractiveTransition' in protocol 'UIViewControllerContextTransitioning' not implemented in SWRevealViewController.m

I see that this is a required for UIViewControllerContextTransitioning but I have no idea how to implement it.  So I just added this

```
- (void)pauseInteractiveTransition {
    // not implemented
}
```

Everything is working fine but I want to know if there is something else I should do.

Comment: I wish I had an answer for you.  I'm in the same boat.  I see this warning also and when looking at the Apple documentation ... it is REQUIRED - https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontrollercontexttransitioning/1829437-pauseinteractivetransition?language=objc . Lets keep this question alive @Stewart Lynch

Comment: It looks like this is new advanced UIView and UIViewcontroller functionality --- Session 216 WWDC 2016.  We should research it and give John-Lluch some help on the topic : https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController